# Get the video duration once the youtube video is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, youtube-api

Im working on a project where I load list of youtube videos to a UITableView. As to load and play them I use the YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper pod. Based on my understanding I use "playerViewDidBecomeReady" delegate method to determine if the video is loaded and once that calls I update my label with the video duration. However for some reason it doesnt get update all the time. My code as bellow. What am I missing

```
func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    print("player is ready to play")

    self.updateLabel(cell:cell,videoView:YTPlayer)
}

 static func updateLabel(cell:UITableViewCell,videoView:YTPlayerView) {

    var videoView = cell.viewWithTag(TABLE_CELL_TAGS.webView) as!  YTPlayerView!
    let durationSecs = String(describing: videoView?.duration())
    var time = videoView?.duration()
    cell.textLabel.text = time
}
```

My UITableViewDelegates as bellow

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:Utils.isIpad() ? "iPadVideosCell":"videosCell", for: indexPath)

  self.cell = cell

  var videoView = cell.viewWithTag(5) as!  YTPlayerView!
  self.YTPlayer = videoView
  videoView?.delegate = self
  return cell
 }
```

Comment: make sure that you connected to delegate

Comment: I did sorry i forgot to add it to the cellforrow, but still no difference with result. what am i missing

Comment: I think your approach can be improved. `self.cell` holds synchronous data. Delegates methods, mainly when talking about network interaction are asynchronous. You can have some trouble in it. I would change the calls. Is your `videoView?.duration()` always returning a value ? Have you tried to call `textLabel` update on main thread ?

Comment: i tried updating the textlabel on main thread but then it crashed